# Can an ASP.NET 4.0 application within an ASP.NET 2.0 site use the same Forms Authentication cookie?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, forms-authentication

**See update at bottom of question**

I have an ASP.NET 2.0 web application (say `https://mysite.somedomain.com/`) which uses forms authentication. I wish to integrate an ASP.NET 4.0 web app within this site, based at `https://mysite.somedomain.com/NewApp/`. Forms Auth is working on the outer app, but the inner app is rejecting the cookie.

`web.config` on the outer (ASP.NET 2.0) web app contains:

```
<httpCookies requireSSL="true"/>
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name="MySiteWebAuth" loginUrl="/Login.aspx" protection="All" 
           path="/" timeout="90" requireSSL="true" slidingExpiration="true"/>  
</authentication>
<machineKey (same machine key is in both configs)  
    validation="SHA1"
    decryption="AES"/>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
  <allow users="*" />
</authorization>
```

`web.config` on the inner (ASP.NET 4.0) web app contains:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name="MySiteWebAuth" loginUrl="/Login.aspx" protection="All" 
           path="/" timeout="90" requireSSL="true" slidingExpiration="true"
           ticketCompatibilityMode="Framework20"/>  
</authentication>
<machineKey (same machine key is in both configs)  
    validation="SHA1"
    decryption="AES"/>
```

This is the code in Login.aspx.cs that sets the cookie on successful authentication:

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = 
    new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
        1, 
        ApplicationContext.User.Identity.Name, 
        DateTime.Now, 
        DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(90), 
        false, 
        ApplicationContext.User.Identity.SessionID.ToString()
    );
HttpCookie cookie = 
   new HttpCookie(
       FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, 
       FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket)
   );

cookie.Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath;
cookie.HttpOnly = true;
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

If I log into the outer web app, then navigate to a page within the inner web app, it does a redirect to the login page and writes `Forms authentication failed for the request. Reason: The ticket supplied was invalid.` to the event log on the server.

How do I get the ASP.NET 2.0 Forms Auth ticket to be accepted by the inner ASP.NET 4.0 web app?

**Update**: It works under HTTPS IIS 7.5, but not under HTTPS IIS 7.0. Doing some more investigation.

**Update 2**: We have applied Server 2008 SP2 to the server along with the recent patch for the hash-collision DoS and since then the cookie sharing has worked.

Comment: It might be worth putting the same decryption and validation attribute values (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8h3skw9(v=VS.100).aspx) as well as the keys just to be sure. This was an issue between asp.net 1.1 and 2

Comment: Just tried that (and updated question), same result.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to keeping nearly all of the aforementioned values the same, you'll need to set the `machineKey` element's `compatibilityMode` attribute in the 4.0 application's configuration file:

```
<machineKey compatibilityMode="Framework20SP2" validationKey="THE_KEY" decryptionKey="ANOTHER_KEY" validation="SHA1" />
```

Comment: THANK YOU FOR THIS! I've been wrestling with this same issue, and this is what fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you read this - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb0zx8fc.aspx - perhaps remove the [ticketCompatibilityMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.ticketcompatibilitymode.aspx) attribute from your 4.0 app, or at least make sure they're the same.

Comment: added domain="thedomain" to the `<forms>` element, same result (Event message: Forms authentication failed for the request. Reason: The ticket supplied was invalid.)

Comment: we have it working on HTTP on IIS7.5 (production environment is HTTPS/IIS7.0), we're just setting it up in HTTPS on 7.5 to eliminate that.

Answer (score 0):

Add this appsetting to both web.config files:

add key="aspnet:UseLegacyFormsAuthenticationTicketCompatibility" value="true"

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure both applications have the same encryption key in the web.config files

```
<machineKey
      validationKey="C50B3C89CB21F4F1422FF158A5B42D0E8DB8CB5CDA1742572A487D9401E3400267682B202B746511891C1BAF47F8D25C07F6C39A104696DB51F17C529AD3CABE" 
      decryptionKey="8A9BE8FD67AF6979E7D20198CFEA50DD3D3799C77AF2B72F" 
      validation="SHA1" />
```

[Forms Authentication Across Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb0zx8fc%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)